# What is the origin of the word "ell"?

Tags: etymology

What is the etymological origin of the word "ell" in its meaning (according to [American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition](http://www.wordnik.com/words/ell)) "A wing of a building at right angles to the main structure"?

Comment: The letter "L" = a shape with a long main axis, with a shorter extension at a right angle to the main.  The word "ell": how you pronounce the name of the letter.

Comment: Similar words can be found in the dictionary for other letters, like [ess](http://dictionary.infoplease.com/ess), [jay](http://dictionary.infoplease.com/jay), [tee](http://dictionary.infoplease.com/tee), [vee](http://dictionary.infoplease.com/vee), and [zee](http://dictionary.infoplease.com/zee), which can refer to the letter, or be occasionally used as a noun or adjective to describe something shaped like the letter. My favorite is [_aitch_](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/aitch).

Comment: I can't closevote as General Reference, so I've chosen Off Topic. As @Hellion says, it's a trivial metaphoric reference to the shape of the letter. You more commonly talk of [an L lounge](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22an+L+lounge%22&aq=f&oq=%22an+L+lounge%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.3715&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) being that shape (often because it's a lounge/diner with the dining table out of sight round the corner from the main sofa).

Comment: [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ell&allowed_in_frame=0) says:   type of building extension, 1773, American English; so called for resemblance to the shape of the alphabet letter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is purely observational. The wing makes the building look like an L from above.

Answer (score 2):

Etymonline says: type of building extension, 1773, American English; so called for resemblance to the shape of the alphabet letter.